# API Contacts are not injecting into Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I have a DE which is getting data via API. Whenever user fill out the form the API triggers and send data to Newsletter DE.

In a Journey builder I setup a campaign using entry source as API event then selected the Newsletter DE. But whenever new contact is added into DE, it does not inject into journey? any idea why the new contact  is not automatically injecting into Journey.

I want as soon as contact added into Newsletter DE, it should be also inject into Journey.

Please advise how do I accomplish this?

Comment: It seems like their a one solution create fire event automation then the de contacts are injecting into journey. But event fire is minimum time frame every after 1 hour. I would like to send email to customer instantly, so as soon as they will the form data feed into de via API and then I want them to be injected into journey which will send them email. Any solution?

Comment: Real time injection is only available with api entry event.  Cloud page entry event. And salesforce entry events

Comment: I tried entry event as API, that also didn't work.

Comment: Can u check that do you have access for journey in API call?
you can check that in postman using your client id and client secret and under the access token, you can see the scope ..if the scope is like below you can able to use API event in journey or esle you cant "scope": "offline automations_read automations_write journeys_execute journeys_read journeys_write data_extensions_read data_extensions_write journeys_aspr journeys_delete",

Comment: I dont think so API have access to Journey. Anyway I am not API developer, what I was told the x DE is feed via API. and I am being asked that as soon  as data reach to DE I have to trigger an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will not work as intended as it seems to be rooted in a misunderstanding about how Journey Builder works. The solution design is not compatible with the design of Journey Builder tool:

As pointed out in the comments, there is no real-time injection based on a condition like "record is in data extension".

When you configure your entry source as "API Event", you only define the data extension that records should be saved in *in the course an incoming API call that injects into the journey*. You do NOT place a sort of "real time listener" on that DE.

In other words:
The process is not intended to work without an injection API call.
The API call is what starts the journey.
Consequently, the data extension record is a *result* of the process of injection via API, not the start of the process of injection.

in sum:

Simply adding a record to the data extension via API will not enable real-time processing, for this you can skip the API call to add to the data extension, but need to use a different API call instead that injects into the journey. This as a "byproduct" stores the record in the DE you specify in the entry source.

Option A)

No API development possible: If you need to work based on the DE alone, you can only do this with the data extension entry event and under most circumstances, an *hourly* automation executing the Journey regularly.

Option B)
involves development:
If A is not helping, then the approach to solve it would be changing the incoming API call.

from current: dump data into a DE

to new: trigger API event while sending data along.
Approach:
inside Marketing Cloud Journey Builder, you setup the data Extension and the API event. You then give the ID of your API Event to a developer.

The developer changes their logic to this API call:

```
POST https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/events
```

headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{accessToken}}
```

```
{
    "ContactKey": "003xxxx",
    "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-0dbe46de-74f9-a309-7778-298c0a565f93",
    "Data": {
        "SubscriberKey": "003xxxx",
        "Email": "yourEmail@yourDomain.xx",
        "First_Name": "a",
        "Last_Name": "b"
    }
}
```

Effect:
Contacts go into the Journey. All data sent along is stored in the DE specified.

APIEvent-0dbe46de-74f9-a309-7778-298c0a565f93 is the ID of the API event you set up in Journey Builder.

SubscriberKey,
Email,
First_Name,
Last_Name ,
are examples for fields in the DE.

Comment: Thanks Jonas...